# UniqueConstraints bundle not picked up by EmbeddableDocumentStore with custom plugins directory

Tags: ravendb

We are using `EmbeddableDocumentStore` for non-production deployments and in general it works great. I stumbled upon an issue which took me few hours to solve and it would be good to know if the behaviour I am experiencing is by design.

I init `EmbeddableDocumentStore` like this:

```
var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore()
{
    DataDirectory = dataDirectory,
    DefaultDatabase = "DbName",
    RunInMemory = false,
    UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true,
};

store.Configuration.Port = 10001;
store.Configuration.PluginsDirectory = pluginsDirectory; // this is the important line
store.Configuration.CompiledIndexCacheDirectory = compiledIntexCacheDirectory;
store.Configuration.Storage.Voron.AllowOn32Bits = true;
store.RegisterListener(new UniqueConstraintsStoreListener());
store.Initialize();
```

With this setup UniqueConstraints are not working on the embedded server.

However, when I put plugins directory to it's default location (WorkingDirectory + /Plugins), it magically starts working. **Is it expected behaviour?**

**More info:**

I can reproduce it in Console app and in Web app. In web app, the default location is web root + /Plugins.

After a little bit of investigation I found out that there is a difference in how UniqueConstraints' triggers are registered in `store.Configuration.Catalog.Catalogs` which might have something to do with the unexpected (for me) behaviour.

With custom PluginDirectory, triggers are registered in store.Configuration.Catalog.Catalogs as `BuiltinFitleringCatalog`:

[image: Custom location]

When bundle is in the default location, triggers are added to `BundlesFilteredCatalog` in `store.Configuration.Catalog.Catalogs` with all other default triggers:

[image: Default location]

Answer (score 0):

What version of RavenDB?

In RavenDB 3.5 registering plugins on the server-side requires a magic string. Adding this to your example above will probably fix it.

```
store.Configuration.Settings =
{
    { "Raven/ActiveBundles", "Unique Constraints" }
};
```